# Google Apps Script: Output each row where cell matches IF statement

Tags: javascript, loops, google-apps-script

Long time lurker and new at fiddling with Google Apps Script. I have a script that checks to make sure things are properly filled out on a large sheet. Right now it works, but is only showing a singular output for each error, I want it to loop through and list each row that is flagged by the IF statement.
(I have a lot more IF statements in here, just removed them for simplification)

```
  function errorTest() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Ad Status");
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    var missingFBorder = "";
    var stillFB = "";



    for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      //check if col 0 is enabled but col 15 is blank, output col 4,5,1 ie City, State (Type)
        if((values[i][0] === "Enabled"||values[i][0] === "Pending Enable"||values[i][0] === "Pending Month-end") && values[i][15] == "") {
            var missingFBorder = "FB order # missing: ";
            missingFBorder += values[i][4] + ", " + values[i][5] + " (" + values[i][1] + ")" + "\n"
        }
        
      //check if col 0 is disabled but col 14 is not false, output col 4,5,1 ie City, State (Type)
        if((values[i][0] === "Disabled"||values[i][0] === "Pending Disable") && values[i][14] != false) {
            var stillFB = "FB ad set still running:";
            stillFB += values[i][4] + ", " + values[i][5] + " (" + values[i][1] + ")" + "\n"
        }

        
    }
    errorTxt = missingFBorder + stillFB;
console.log(errorTxt);
  }
```

I have tried a few things, I am just not very familiar with loops when using google apps script. The code works great for returning singular errors, but not multiple as desired.

---

UPDATE
I have it working, although it is not very pretty. Rather than overwriting the variable each time (thanks for pointing that out Cooper) I check if the variable is still empty before adding the variable title and skip if so.

```
function errorTest() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("YRC Ad Status");
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    var missingFBorder = "";
    var stillFB = "";



    for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      //check if col 0 is enabled but col 15 is blank, output col 4,5,1 ie City, State (Type)
        if((values[i][0] === "Enabled"||values[i][0] === "Pending Enable"||values[i][0] === "Pending Month-end") && values[i][15] == "") {
            missingFBorder += values[i][4] + ", " + values[i][5] + " (" + values[i][1] + ")" + "\n"
        }
        
      //check if col 0 is disabled but col 14 is not false, output col 4,5,1 ie City, State (Type)
        if((values[i][0] === "Disabled"||values[i][0] === "Pending Disable") && values[i][14] != false) {
            var stillFB = "FB ad set still running:";
            stillFB += values[i][4] + ", " + values[i][5] + " (" + values[i][1] + ")" + "\n"
        }
    }
    if(missingFBorder != "") {
    var missingFBorder = "FB order # missing: " + missingFBorder;
    }
    if(stillFB != "") {
    var stillFB = "FB ad set still running:"; + missingFBorder;
    }
    
    errorTxt = missingFBorder + stillFB;
console.log(errorTxt);
  }
```

Comment: Your redeclaring var `missingFBorder` and `stillFB` on each loop so you're not seeing the results from every loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
function errorTest() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let sh = ss.getSheetByName("Ad Status");
  let vs = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  let arr1 = ["Enabled","Pending Enable","Pending Menth-end"];
  let arr2 = ["Disabled","Pending Disable"]
  let missingFBorder = "";
  let stillFB = "";
  vs.forEach((r,i) => {
    if(~arr1.indexOf(r[0])&& r[15] === ""){
      missingFBorder += `FB order # missing: ${r[4]}, ${r[5]} (${r[1]})\n`;
    }
    if(~arr2.indexOf(r[0]) && r[14] == false) {
      stillFB += `FB ad set still running: ${r[4]}, ${r[5]} ($r[1]) \n`;
    }
  })
  console.log(`${missingFBorder}${stillFB}`);
}
```

Right now you are redeclaring missingFBorder and stillFB on every loop

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply - did not even realize that I was overwriting each time. I tried your solution and it's spitting out:ReferenceError: vs is not defined
errorTest @ Code.gs:9

Comment: I have updated my original question with a very untidy fix

Comment: I modified my code and I am not interested in rereading your question.  Whatever value you can get from my answer is my  answer.